# MySQL count and total

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a number of votes recorded in it, each vote goes against a post. What I want to be able to do is count the total occurances of each vote.

Table looks like this:

```
    vote
    -----
    1
    2
    3
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    2
    2
    2
    2
    ...and so on...
```

How can I count the records, e.g. In that list 1x2, 2x6, 3x2, 4x1 and 5x1 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want you can use GROUP BY and COUNT:

```
SELECT vote, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM votes
GROUP BY vote
```

Result:

```
vote  cnt
1     2  
2     6  
3     2  
4     1  
5     1
```

Votes that have zero count will not be represented in this result set. If you want to have these included with a count of zero then you will need to use an OUTER JOIN with a table listing all the possible votes.

```
SELECT
    possible_votes.vote,
    COUNT(votes.vote) AS cnt
FROM possible_votes
LEFT JOIN votes ON possible_votes.vote = votes.vote
GROUP BY possible_votes.vote
```

Result:

```
vote  cnt
1     2  
2     6  
3     2  
4     1  
5     1  
6     0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select vote, count(votes) as vt
from t_your_table
group by vote
```

Comment: How do I echo the result in PHP?

Comment: if you are using $row = mysql_fetch_object($result), then you can use $row->vote, and $row->vt (which is the total vote for that particular $row->vote).

Answer (score 1):

Check MySQL manual for GROUP BY combined with COUNT.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT vote, COUNT(*) as total
FROM votes
GROUP BY vote
```